# App for recording lectures

Tags: applications, notes, voice-recording

I am a mathematics graduate student looking for ways to improve my note taking. I have been experimenting with recording lectures with my Galaxy S5 (using Coji, which is a great app), but I am now on the market for something a bit more specific.

I want to be able to start the recording at the beginning of lecture, and take pictures of the board throughout class without stopping the recording. Some of the mathematics being taught is pretty hairy, and it takes some time staring at pictures of the board and at your notebook to get it. I would also like to be able to split the hour and a half long recorded file into smaller segments afterwards, say segments going over this or that proof. An app that puts this all into individual sessions (like Coji) would be a plus as well.

Does anyone have any familiarity with an app that has this functionality? I haven't had much luck finding something that hits all the key points.